# Iterative Deepening A* Star Explanation

Tags: java, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, iterative-deepening

Can somebody explain about **Iterative Deepening A***? I still don't understand how it works.
**Iterative deepening** search w/ **Depth First Search**, and If still not found the solution; increase the **Depth**++ until found solution.

If Iterative deepening using **Depth**, then Iterative Deepening A* use what to limit their search?

Here are a picture if you need to explain how it IDA* Works, i just don't understand how it works.

**(1,2,4,9)** and etc, is the step

0+2=2 is **f(n)=g(n)+h(n)**

[image: IDA* EXAMPLE]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If Iterative deepening using Depth, then Iterative Deepening A* use what to limit their search?

The naive implementation of IDA* would just have something like `threshold++` at the end of every iteration, similar to your `depth++` above. This is to keep IDA* admissible.

A better algorithm (that still keeps IDA* admissible) would be to increase the threshold by the next smallest g() cost that is available (from the closed set to the open set).

See: http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~jonathan/PREVIOUS/Courses/657/Notes/10.Single-agentSearch.pdf

Comment: `search a node as long as f <= threshold` so, if the f() cost <= threshold, then increase the threshold++. What is the first value for the **threshold**?

Comment: @yudayyy The value of the smallest outgoing edge from the start node.

Comment: Actually, if you generate the f-cost of the child and detect it is outside of the current f-cost bound, then you should use the lowest f-cost of an unexplored child, not just the f-cost of the parent plus the g-cost to the child.